# can not get sum of lable text value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working with jQuery. I have created one form and its input field.

I have display input field value into lable and than want to get total sum of that lable. SO I have written code like below :

```
   $("#band_members").keyup(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (!isNaN(val)){
            var ttl_band = val*30;
            $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').text(ttl_band);
            calculateSum();
        }
    });

    $('#dj').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (!isNaN(val)){
            $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').text(val);
            calculateSum();
        }
    });

    $("#extra_round").keyup(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (!isNaN(val)){
            var ex_round = val*100;
            $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').text(ex_round);
            calculateSum();
        }
    })
```

And my calculateSum function is looks like below:

```
 function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    jQuery(".numLabel").each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.text) && this.text.length!=0) {
            alert(this.text);

            sum += parseFloat(this.text);
            //console.log(sum);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    jQuery(".total_sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

But here my function is not call. So what should I have to change in my jQuery?

Comment: add your html or provide us a snippert or https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: This is my [link](https://jsfiddle.net/n0nzs8d8/). Where you can see my code

Comment: You need to use `$(this).text()` instead of `this.text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label doesn't have the `text` property, So you need to use either [`$(this).text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`this.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

```
function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    jQuery(".numLabel").each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text(); //this.textContent
        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(text) && text.length != 0) {
            //alert(text);

            sum += parseFloat(text);
            //console.log(sum);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    jQuery(".total_sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tm9yq3wr/)